# Chrome CSS Height Property different from Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying do display a little block which is actually a .png image.

I set the image properties of the little block using css to have 2% width and 2% height.

This image is inside the body, which is set at 100% width, and 100% height.

My problem is, the image comes out correctly in firefox, as in, it looks like a square, but in Chrome, it looks like a rectangle. The image width seems to be correct (2%) but the height seems to not be correct.

Here are pics to illustrate my example:

Firefox: (this is what i want)

[image]

Chrome: (this is what I do not want. I want it to look like how it looks in firefox).

[image]

I'm using html with javascript inside and css and here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testlayout.css" />
<script>    

var x;

function myFunction()
{                   
    var img = new Image(); 
    img.src = 'bgimage.png';
    document.body.appendChild( img );                                       
};

</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()"> 

</body>
</html>
```

And here's my css:

```
body
{
margin:0; padding: 0; cellspacing: 0;
line-height: 0;  /* removes gap betwen rows */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

img
{
height: 2%;
width: 2%;
}
```

That's all. If you guys know what the problem is, please let me know, any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Window sizes on firefox and chrome can differ. In this kind of situations use pixel values instead of percents.

```
img 
{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `* {margin:0;padding:0}` to the beginning of your css file.

Also look into adding a CSS Reset

edit:

Now that I think about it, are you sure bgimage.png exists in that directory? You could also try setting `img.width` and `img.height` within your javascript sort of like this

http://jsfiddle.net/2Uk53/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your body may be set to `height: 100%`, but its parent container (html) isn't.